# Why do I have two docks on the desktop?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

My desktop shows docks on two positions, one on the right and one on the bottom of the screen, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot showing two docks]

How can I exclude the right one?

The GNOME extensions that are currently active in my system are:

1. Dash to Dock
2. User themes